# Python dataframe accumulation line plot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have daily precipitation in a DataFrame, `df`, that looks like:

```
   Jan   Feb   Mar   Apr   May   Jun   Jul   
0   0.00  0.00  0.07  0.02  0.00  0.00   NaN  
1   0.80   NaN  0.00  0.00  0.03  0.00  0.00  
2   0.20  0.00   NaN  0.14  0.00  0.00  0.00 
3   0.00  0.00  0.00  0.01  0.00  0.00  0.00  
4    NaN   NaN  0.00  0.00  0.90  0.50  0.00  
5   0.01  0.00  0.00  0.12  0.17   NaN  0.77  
6   0.77   NaN   NaN  0.00  0.18   NaN  0.00  
7   0.00   NaN  0.04  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.11  
8   0.00  0.56  0.00  0.00  0.02  0.00  0.00  
9   0.00  0.00  0.04  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  
10  0.16  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.42  0.00  0.00  
11  0.00  0.08  0.00  0.00  0.78  0.00  0.00  
...
```

for all days of each month for a year. I would like to plot all of this data onto a single running line chart that shows accumulation (i.e. if it rains on days 1 and 3, then the point to plot for day 3 would be the total rain of days 1+3, then if it rains on day 5, the plot would be days 1+3+5 and so on). What is the best way to add the values and plot like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're looking for [`.stack()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html).  However, your problem seems slighty more complicated than just `.stack()` + `.cumsum()`.  This is because, assuming you have a 31x12 DataFrame (day rows, month columns), you need to tell pandas how to map each month/day combination to a day of the year; otherwise, pandas will assume you have 372-day years.  The first function below does that, and the lines below first create some example data and then use that function to assist with getting a cumulative sum by day-of-year.

```
import datetime


def stack_daily(df, year='current'):
    """Construct pd.DatetimeIndex from unstacked day/month format."""
    # Confirm index is 1-indexed and ends at 31
    if not np.array_equal(df.index, pd.RangeIndex(1, 32)):
        raise ValueError('`df` should have `pd.RangeIndex(1, 32)`')
    # Same logic for columns
    if not np.array_equal(df.columns, pd.RangeIndex(1, 13)):
        raise ValueError('`df` should have columns `pd.RangeIndex(1, 13)`')
    if year == 'current':
        year = datetime.date.today().year
    stacked = df.stack()  # Implicit dropna=True
    day, month = zip(*stacked.index.get_values())
    dates = {'year': [year] * stacked.shape[0],
             'month': month,
             'day': day}
    return pd.to_datetime(dates)


# Create random precipitation data
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


np.random.seed(123)
data = np.empty((31, 12))
data[:] = np.nan
mask = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=data.shape, dtype=np.bool)
vals = np.random.rand(*data.shape)
data[mask] = vals[mask]
data[29:] = np.nan
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=pd.RangeIndex(1, 32),
                  columns=pd.RangeIndex(1, 13))

# Manipulate to get day-of-year index
idx = stack_daily(df)
doy = idx.dt.dayofyear

total_precip = df.stack().reset_index(drop=True)
total_precip.index = doy
total_precip.dropna(inplace=True)
total_precip = total_precip.sort_index().cumsum()

# %matplotlib inline
total_precip.plot()
```

[image]

#### Update

New function:

```
import datetime


def stack_daily(df, year='current', sort=True, dropna=True):
    """Construct pd.DatetimeIndex from unstacked day/month format."""
    # Confirm index is 1-indexed and ends at 31
    if not np.array_equal(df.index, pd.RangeIndex(1, 32)):
        raise ValueError('`df` should have `pd.RangeIndex(1, 32)`')
    # Same logic for columns
    if not np.array_equal(df.columns, pd.RangeIndex(1, 13)):
        raise ValueError('`df` should have columns `pd.RangeIndex(1, 13)`')
    if year == 'current':
        year = datetime.date.today().year
    stacked = df.stack(dropna=False)
    year = np.repeat(year, stacked.shape[0])  # len == 372
    day, month = zip(*stacked.index.get_values())

    # Drop the *difference* between a valid calendar and the 372-day calendar
    #     created by using 12 31-day months.
    # Use a pure-Python solution here because NumPy set logic doesn't generally
    #     support 2d arrays and we have fairly small data (1 year).
    true_dates = pd.date_range(start='{}-01-01'.format(year[0]),
                               end='{}-12-31'.format(year[0]))
    true_dates = list(zip(true_dates.day,
                          true_dates.month,
                          true_dates.year))
    full_dates = list(zip(day, month, year))
    # We want a boolean mask False where dates are invalid
    # This should yield len(mask[mask == 1]) == 365
    mask = np.array([date in true_dates for date in full_dates])

    # Now filter stacked data on this mask
    stacked = stacked.loc[mask]

    # And finally repeat above process converting to datetime
    #     and then getting day of year.
    day, month = zip(*stacked.index.get_values())
    dates = {'year': year[:stacked.shape[0]].tolist(),
             'month': month,
             'day': day}
    stacked.index = pd.to_datetime(dates).dt.dayofyear

    if sort:
        stacked.sort_index(inplace=True)
    if dropna:
        stacked.dropna(inplace=True)
    return stacked
```

Example:

```
# Create random precipitation data
# This gets you a DataFrame with 12 months on the columns and
#     31 days on the index.  Both are 1-indexed i.e. start at 1.
#     There is a mix of 0.00s, NaN, and other floats, mimicking
#     the data from your question.
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(123)
data = np.zeros((31, 12))
mask1 = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=data.shape, dtype=np.bool)
mask2 = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=data.shape, dtype=np.bool)
vals = np.random.rand(*data.shape)
nans = np.zeros(data.shape)
nans[:] = np.nan
data[mask1] = vals[mask1]
data[mask2] = nans[mask2]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=pd.RangeIndex(1, 32),
                  columns=pd.RangeIndex(1, 13))

# %matplotlib inline
stack_daily(df).cumsum().plot()
```

[image]

Comment: I get an error "RuntimeError: Locator attempting to generate 1468 ticks from 0.2 to 366.8: exceeds Locator.MAXTICKS". I have never seen this error before.

Comment: Unfortunately not. After making sure my dataframe is the right size and applying your code, I still get an error "ValueError: cannot assemble the datetimes: day is out of range for month". Will continue to work on it.

Comment: Edit: I was getting that error on a leap year. I tried it on a non-leap year and the script worked perfectly! Will try to see whats going on with that leap year.... Thanks!!!

Comment: Updated @JMP0629

Comment: This works great. Is there a simple way to place the month ticks with month labels on the x axis instead of Julian days?

Comment: Yes.  Don't replace the index with the "day of year."  Just use `pd.to_datetime(dates)`.